# How do I run a state machine once in an Arduino loop

Tags: arduino, state-machine, multitasking

I am attempting to photograph water drop collisions using two solenoids.  I have successfully done this using one solenoid.  This used setting delays in the code to time the camera shutter, water drops and flash.  I would like to trigger two solenoids at the same time with identical delays but not sure how to do this.

The order of operation should be

1. Open the camera shutter (camera is in bulb mode)
2. Drop two water drops from two solenoids at the same time.
3. Fire the flash
4. Close the camera shutter

My platform is an Atmega 2560.  Here is the code I have so far,

```c
int relayCam=A0;  //pin to relay to trigger camera
int relayFlash=A7 ;  //pin to relay to fire flash
int button1Read;
//button read delays (settling time)
int button1DT=250;
int button1Pin=8;  //pin for 2 drop button read
int DelayCamOpen=100;  //wait time to trigger camera
int DelayCamClose=1000;  //wait time to close camera shutter
//Drop start
int DropStart=500;  //time to start first drop
//Flash timing
int DelayFlashFire1=350;
int DelayFlashOff=50;  //turn flash off

bool runOnce = false;

class Solenoid
{
 int SolenoidPin;
 long OnTime;
 long OffTime;
 int SolenoidState;
 unsigned long previousMillis;
  
public:
Solenoid(int pin, long on, long off)
{
SolenoidPin = pin;
pinMode(SolenoidPin, OUTPUT);
OnTime = on;
OffTime = off;
SolenoidState = HIGH;
previousMillis = 0;
}
void update()
{
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
if((SolenoidState == HIGH) && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= OnTime))
{
SolenoidState = HIGH;
previousMillis = currentMillis;
digitalWrite(SolenoidPin, SolenoidState);  
}
else if ((SolenoidState == LOW) && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= OffTime))
{
SolenoidState = LOW;
previousMillis = currentMillis;
digitalWrite(SolenoidPin, SolenoidState);  
}
}
};

Solenoid drop1(A1, 55, 55);
Solenoid drop2(A2, 55, 55);

void setup()
{
pinMode(relayCam, OUTPUT);
pinMode(relayFlash, OUTPUT);
pinMode(button1Pin, INPUT);
}
void loop()
{
//This part works
button1Read=digitalRead(button1Pin);
delay (button1DT);
if(button1Read==0) {
delay (DelayCamOpen);  //wait time after button is pushed to start sequence
digitalWrite (relayCam,LOW);  //opens the camera shutter
delay (DropStart);  //wait time after shutter opens ro start first drop
//This part does not execute
if (runOnce == false)
{runOnce = true;
drop1.update();
drop2.update();
}
//This part works
delay (DelayFlashFire1);  //wait time to fire flash
digitalWrite (relayFlash,LOW);  //fire flash
delay (DelayFlashOff);  //time to keep flash open (very short time)
digitalWrite (relayFlash,HIGH);  //close flash relay
delay  (DelayCamClose);  //wait time to close camera shutter
digitalWrite (relayCam,HIGH);  //close camera shutter
} 
else if(button1Read==1) 
{
 digitalWrite (drop1,HIGH);  //no signal to waterdrop
 digitalWrite (drop2,HIGH);  //no signal to waterdrop
 digitalWrite (relayCam,HIGH);  //no signal to camera
 digitalWrite (relayFlash,HIGH);  //no signal to flash
}
}
```

The camera and flash portion is working but the solenoids do not.  I'm not sure if I'm even going about this correctly.  I do know that having delays to run two solenoids is not giving me the desired results, hence trying to use the state machine method.  Any help/suggestions is greatly appreciated.  I am new to writing code and all things Arduino.

This is the code that works with one solenoid.

```c
//Pin assignments
int relayCam=A0;  //pin to relay to trigger camera
int relayFlash=A7 ;  //pin to relay to fire flash
int relayWD1=A1;  //pin to relay to trigger water drop 1
int button1Read;
//button read delays (settling time)
int button1DT=250;

int button1Pin=8;  //pin for 2 drop button read
//drop sizes
int dropSize1=55;  //time to hold relay for 1st drop
int dropSize2=45;  //time to hold relay for 2nd drop

//delays betwween drops
int Delay1=45;  //time between 1st and 2nd drops
//camera shutter timings
int DelayCamOpen=100;  //wait time to trigger camera
int DelayCamClose=1000;  //wait time to close camera shutter
//Drop start
int DropStart=500;  //time to start first drop
//Flash timing
int DelayFlashFire1=350;
int DelayFlashOff=50;  //turn flash off

void setup() {
pinMode(relayCam, OUTPUT);  
pinMode(relayWD1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(relayFlash, OUTPUT);
pinMode(button1Pin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
button1Read=digitalRead(button1Pin);
delay (button1DT);
if(button1Read==0) {
delay (DelayCamOpen);  //wait time after button is pushed to start sequence
digitalWrite (relayCam,LOW);  //opens the camera shutter
delay (DropStart);  //wait time after shutter opens ro start first drop  
  
digitalWrite (relayWD1,LOW);  //starts first drop
delay (dropSize1);  //duration of water flow
digitalWrite (relayWD1,HIGH);  //stops first drop
  
delay (Delay1);  //wait time for second drop to start
  
digitalWrite (relayWD1,LOW);  //start of second drop
delay (dropSize2);  //duration of waterflow
digitalWrite (relayWD1,HIGH);  //stops second drop

delay (DelayFlashFire1);  //wait time to fire flash
digitalWrite (relayFlash,LOW);  //fire flash
delay (DelayFlashOff);  //time to keep flash open (very short time)
digitalWrite (relayFlash,HIGH);  //close flash relay
delay  (DelayCamClose);  //wait time to close camera shutter
digitalWrite (relayCam,HIGH);  //close camera shutter
} 
else if(button1Read==1) 
{digitalWrite (relayWD1,HIGH);  //no signal to waterdrop
 digitalWrite (relayCam,HIGH);  //no signal to camera
 digitalWrite (relayFlash,HIGH);  //no signal to flash
}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your intention behind `runOnce`?  Are you intending to have an inner loop that calls `update()` until the drop is finished?  Or is it related to the outer loop such that you want a drop only for the first invocation of `loop()`?

Comment: My intention of `runOnce` is to only run the solenoids once inside the loop depending on the button state.   The button is used to start the sequence and the solenoids should only activate for two drops each.  One button push runs the loop one time through.  The loop switches states once the button is released.  Button read = 0 starts the sequence.  Once the first sequence completes and the button is released it reads the second part of the loop turning everything off.  The issue I have now is that the solenoids run continuously.  Not sure how to make them stop once the button is released.

Answer (score 0):

The abstraction represented by your `update()` method is tortured and confusing to me.  My suggestion is to replace `update()` with two methods `startDrop()` and `stopDrop()`.  `startDrop()` records a `startTimestamp` (like you've done with `currentMillis` but a class member variable) and opens the solenoid.  `stopDrop()` compares the elapsed time and returns false if not enough time has passed and the solenoid remains open, or returns true if enough time has passed and the solenoid is closed.

```
class Solenoid
{
  ...
  
  private unsigned long startTimestamp;

  void startDrop()
  {
    startTimestamp = millis();
    digitalWrite(SolenoidPin, LOW);  
  }
  
  bool stopDrop()
  {
    if ((millis() - startTimestamp) >= OffTime)
    {
      digitalWrite(SolenoidPin, HIGH);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  ...
}


void loop()
{
  ...
  
  drop1.startDrop();
  drop2.startDrop();
  while (drop1.stopDrop() == false);
  while (drop2.stopDrop() == false);
  
  ...
}
```

That's just a rough draft.  You might want to add some error checking to ensure that, for example, the solenoid was closed before `startDrop()` or that `startDrop()` was called before `stopDrop()`.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to review this.  I am tortured and confused by much of this.  I understand the mechanics of the single solenoid code.  Adding the second solenoid and timing it with the first is quite confusing.  I tried wiring the solenoids in parallel but I need to adjust the drop timings independently.  I implemented the code above but received an error that the `startDrop` and `stopDrop` were `private`.  I made them `public` and they now run continuously regardless of the `buttonState`  I also had to declare `currentMillis`.

Comment: Whoops, my `currentMillis` should be `millis()`.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @brichardson I realized my answer code will not work correctly if `drop2.onTime < drop1.onTime` because it doesn't attempt to stop drop2 until after drop1 has been stopped.  So some improvements are needed to be more flexible with the on times.

Comment: Thanks again for reviewing.  I'm not 100% sure that a state machine is the best solution for this.  I will investigate other options.  Maybe Arduino just can't do what I want???